# Unexpected activity is returned from fragments context in nested navigation graph

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm building a modular project with 3 relevant modules for this problem. `app`, `core` and `launch`.

The `app` module depends on all other modules, `core` module depends on neither `app` nor `launch`. And `launch` depends on `core`.

I'm using Jetpack's Navigation component with a `nav_app` acting as the app's root navigation graph and `nav_launch` included in it acting as the launch feature's navigation graph. (Noting that `nav_launch` is located in the `launch` module and `app_nav` is located in the `app` module.

Each module has its own root `Activity`. The problem is that in `LaunchFragment`, `nav_launch`'s starting destination when I ask for `context` it returns an instance of `MainActivity` which is the root activity for `nav_app` navigation graph, shouldn't it return `LaunchActivity` which is the direct parent of it?

What is causing this behavior and how can I access `LaunchActivity`?

Comment: What does `shouldn't it return LaunchActivity which is the direct parent of it` mean? If your `NavHostFragment` is in `MainActivity`, why would your context be anything but `MainActivity`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes but I also have a ```NavHostFragment``` in ```LaunchFragment``` which is included in the ```nav_app```. Why does the context ignore it and return the root one?

Comment: Nesting fragments within fragments doesn't change what activity you're on. What gave you the impression that you'd be on a different activity?